# Dart. No warnings and errors when class doesn't implement an interface

Tags: dart

I can't understand this "weird" behavior of dart. Look at the sample above:

```dart
abstract class Swimmer {
  int numOfSwim;
  Swim();
}

class Human implements Swimmer {

}
```

When I run this code there is no warning and errors. I start dartium with `DART_FLAGS='--enable_type_checks --enable_asserts'`. What the hell? How the class can implement an interface if it actually doesn't.. Looks like Dart is a little bit loose.

May be Dart has some **mode** to be more strict.

Comment: If you run this in the DartEditor you will see the following warning: `Missing concrete implementation of setter 'Swimmer.numOfSwim', 'Swimmer.Swim' and getter 'Swimmer.numOfSwim'`

Comment: I use Intellij. It about language and not IDE. It is good if DartEditor can recognize this folly, but I don't use it)

Comment: Well, DartEditor just hooks into the [Dart Analyzer](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/analyzer/). IntelliJ does the same, and gives the same warning for me.

Comment: Hm `dartanalyzer` - much better! May be Dartium has additional flag to show warnings like this in the console? If not, please add suggestion about using `dartanalyzer` - I accept it.

Comment: I've added a more fully fleshed explanation that differentiates between warnings and errors.

Comment: apparently you're still learning the core principles of programming, `abstract` classes are not necessarily interfaces, they simply define non-instantiable, inheritable classes which _can_ be inherited and _can_ define a common class signature - but you're not forced to do so since abstract classes can provide implementations themselves -- if no concrete implementation is found your runtime or compiler will throw a warning, as has already been stated. If you want to define actual `interface`s you need to use the correct keyword for it.

Comment: @specializt FYI, in Dart every class defines an implicit interface, and therefore abstract classes are the correct way to specify an interface. There is no special `interface` keyword. See [Abstract Classes](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#abstract-classes) and the next section on implicit interfaces.

Comment: @specializt - this in not about programming it's about abstract concepts of Dart's object-oriented ideology. Thanks for explanation. `interface` keyword is deprecated: http://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/proposal-to-eliminate-interface.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Dart spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-408.pdf) states (p38):

> It is a static warning if a concrete class does not have an
>   implementation for a method in any of its superinterfaces unless it
>   declares its own noSuchMethod method (10.10).

Static warnings are useful for developers to catch mistakes but do not interfere with the execution of a Dart program. Errors on the other hand do have an effect on program execution. You can read more about the difference between warning and errors on page 10 of the Dart spec.

Since this is the case, running your code in Dartium will work just fine, since a missing method implementation is just a warning, not an error. If you want to catch these warnings, you can use the [Dart Analyzer](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/analyzer/) which will check for warnings and errors. IDEs such as Dart Editor and IntelliJ integrate the analyzer, so you don't have to run it manually.

For instance, in Dart Editor your code will display the following warning:

> Missing concrete implementation of setter 'Swimmer.numOfSwim',
>   'Swimmer.Swim' and getter 'Swimmer.numOfSwim'